# How to read struct.pack encoded string in Objective-C?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, sockets

I have a Python server that sends data to the client as bytes using the struct.pack function. The data is constructed as `struct.pack("!bhhh", 0x1, x, y, z)`.

How do I read back all the arguments on the client side in Objecive-C?

I use the following code right now: 
`NSString *command = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`
and get a result as 
`ÿÿÿø`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `!` prefix, the data is written in Big Endian. This prevents you from simply type-casting your input data to the appropriate type.

Therefore, you need to calculate the Words (your three `h` values) using bitwise shifting. You can easily create a macro to simplify this:

```
// Read a byte (b) from buf at pos
#define GET_B(buf, pos) (uint8)buf[0]
// Read a (signed) word (H) from buf at pos
#define GET_h(buf, pos) ((int8_t)buf[pos+1] | (int8_t)buf[pos]<<8)
// Read an (unsigned) word (h) from buf at pos
#define GET_H(buf, pos) ((uint8)buf[pos+1] | (uint8)buf[pos]<<8)
```

Using this with some example input looks like this:

```
    // created with struct.pack('!bhhh', 1, -200, -300, -400)
    unsigned char input[] = {0x01, 0xff, '8', 0xfe, 0xd4, 0xfe, 'p'};

    NSLog(@"a: %d", GET_B(input, 0));
    NSLog(@"x: %d", GET_h(input, 1));
    NSLog(@"y: %d", GET_h(input, 3));
    NSLog(@"z: %d", GET_h(input, 5));
```

Please be aware how many bytes the different data types occupy. `b` is just one byte, but `h` is two. Therefore the offsets are 0, 1, 3 and 5.

Comment: Thanks, that made me understand how it works. I still have a trouble with signed integers. I am trying with (int16_t)buf[pos] with pos = 1,2,3 but it overflows for negative values.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that "h" is actually signed. I updated my post. So now you have GET_h for signed and GET_H for unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't string data. Don't use NSString.

You need to define a structure with an equivalent layout. This is a bit tricky, because the structure you're using is oddly aligned:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
    uint8_t b;
    uint16_t h1, h2, h3;
} *bhhh = (void *) buffer;
```

You can now refer to the contents of the field as `bhhh->b`, `bhhh->h1`, etc.

Note that the names I'm using are all totally bogus, because I have no idea what the data represents. Don't copy them verbatim.